# What is incorrect in ZIP command line?

Tags: command-line, zip

I am developing AWS Lambda (NET6). During the Github action execution (build, zip, upload) in a CloudFormation yml file, I have received the error:

```
Run zip -jr customerlambda-356e9e4b8869b2cf7f483d739aa5a8aa34e0fc13.zip -i ./bin/Release/net6.0/publish/*

zip error: Invalid command arguments (nothing to select from)
Error: Process completed with exit code 16.
```

It is in Ubuntu-latest environment.

What is incorrect here?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
zip -jr customerlambda-356e9e4b8869b2cf7f483d739aa5a8aa34e0fc13.zip \
./bin/Release/net6.0/publish/
```

i.e. **without** `-i` ... With the `-i`(*include*) option, you still haven't specified the path to the source file(s)/directory(ies) and hence the error:

```
zip error: Invalid command arguments (nothing to select from)
```

##### Notice one:

`./bin/Release/net6.0/publish/` seems to be the relative path to where your source files/directories are, but adding `-i` before it will turn it into an argument to the `-i` option instead of an argument to the `zip` command itself ... Therefore as far as the `zip` command is concerned, there is no source file/directory argument ... and, you don't need to include that directory's contents with `-i` as the `-r` option will recurse through the contents of that directory so you dont need to use `*`(*which you better escape with a backslash `\*` when used*) either ... So simply remove `-i` and `*`.

##### Notice two:

The `-j` option will result in `zip` storing just the name(s) of a saved file(s) and  not  storing  directory names(*i.e. paths relative to the current directory*) ... That might cause a problem when used with the `-r` option as duplicate identical filenames might exist in sub-directories that will be recursed by the option `-r` set which will result in `zip` receiving repeated filenames to store in the archive which it cannot do and will result in an error like:

```
zip error: Invalid command arguments (cannot repeat names in zip file)
```

So, you might not want to use `-j` in that case.

##### Notice three:

While relative paths in the form of `./subdir/subdir2/` and `archive.zip` will work and be parsed relative to the current working directory, it might be a good idea in scriptfiles to use the full real path for both the output archive and the source directory(ies)/file(s) like for example if your source directory is:

```
/home/runner/work/PM2AWSCustomers/PM2AWSCustomers/bin/Release/net6.0/publish/
```

and you want the resulting archive file named to be `customerlambda.zip` and saved in:

```
/home/runner/work/PM2AWSCustomers/
```

then use the `zip` command like so:

```
zip -r /home/runner/work/PM2AWSCustomers/customerlambda.zip \
/home/runner/work/PM2AWSCustomers/PM2AWSCustomers/bin/Release/net6.0/publish/
```

the backslash `\` is used to escape the newline used for redability purposes in this post and will make the shell read the command as one liner ignoring the escaped newline.

Comment: These are source files ./bin/Release/net6.0/publish/

Comment: @ZedZip That is clear to me, but adding `-i` before it will turn it into an argument to the `-i` option instead of an argument to the `zip` command itself ... Therefore as far as the `zip` command is concerned, there is no source file/directory argument ... and, you don't need to include that directory's contents with `-i` as the `-r` option will recurse through the contents of that directory so you dont need to use `*`(*which you better escape with a backslash when used*) either ... So simply remove `-i` and `*`.

Comment: I have added pwd  and ls command to understand what is the current directory for zip

Comment: It is /home/runner/work/PM2AWSCustomers/PM2AWSCustomers
PM2AWSCustomers <----folder
PM2AWSCustomers.sln
README.md
aws
I.e. I need to zip files in  the folder PM2AWSCustomers/bin/Release/net6.0/publish what zip command should be in this case?

Comment: @ZedZip I updated the answer for that ... I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Thank you @Raffa, so finally (without -j, -i and * at the end) : zip -r /home/runner/work/PM2AWSCustomers/customerlambda.zip \
/home/runner/work/PM2AWSCustomers/PM2AWSCustomers/bin/Release/net6.0/publish/

Comment: Thank you @Raffa, now it works!!! :-)

Comment: @ZedZip You're welcome ... I'm glad I could help :-)